# Xamarin.Android ItemSelected event not working on Spinner widgets

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm quite a newbie to Xamarin as well as Android programming.
I have a problem with Spinner widget.
It used to work fine as a normal widget when embedded in AXML file.
Now I need to create and show it on the fly at runtime and I called PerformClick() method.
It shows properly but ItemSelected() event is not firing. I tried googling for two days but no luck.
You can refer my code example below.
I appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ...

    Spinner spinnerPipeIDColumn1 = new Spinner(this, SpinnerMode.Dialog);
    spinnerPipeIDColumn1.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.EditTextStyle);
    spinnerPipeIDColumn1.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
    {
         Toast.MakeText(this, "Hey", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    };

    ...
}
```

Comment: The spinner is populated from csv file in Assets folder using `ArrayAdapter` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution.
I asked for help to my senior staff and he answered me right away.

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.RootLayout);
rootLayout.AddView(spinnerPipeIDColumn1);
```

After adding the lines above, it worked like a charm.

I hope this would be helpful for people seeking a similar problem.